# Removing backslashes when using Oracle's JSON_ARRAY function?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle, plsql

How do you get rid of the back slashes, but still keep the double quotes when using json_array?

TABLE A:

```
 Hospital  Cat    Dog    Lizard   Mouse
 Hosp1            D               M
 Hosp2      C     D       L 
 Hosp3      C     D       L       M
```

Wrong code:

```
 select json_array (regexp_replace(
        case when Cat    = 'C' then '"cat",'    end) ||
        case when Dog    = 'D' then '"dog",'    end) ||
        case when Lizard = 'L' then '"lizard",' end) ||
        case when Mouse  = 'M' then '"mouse",'  end,                                                                                                       
    '",$','')
  ) pets from A where Hospital = Hosp2;
```

Wrong output:

```
 PETS
 ["\"cat\",\"dog\",\"lizard"]
```

Desired output:

```
 PETS
 ["cat","dog","lizard"]
```

And yes, I know you can just concatenate like so `"select '['||` etc. without using the json_array, but I need to have that in the code. Is there a way to use regexp_replace somehow, to get rid of that \ ?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for concatenation:

```
select json_array (
         case when Cat    = 'C' then 'cat'    end,
         case when Dog    = 'D' then 'dog'    end,
         case when Lizard = 'L' then 'lizard' end,
         case when Mouse  = 'M' then 'mouse'  end) as pets 
from A 
where Hospital = 'Hosp2';
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5897c28352223da50798d6b82e35a8f2)

Comment: Sorry, but I need the double quotes around each item (see desired output). Thanks!

Comment: @BFF: which that solution will add

Comment: Holy cow, I'm blind! Sorry I'm not at my desk, so I was just looking at it through my phone. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score -1):

The main reason you get a slash is due to **" (quotes),** as this is a special character so it need delimiter before it, which is a slash.
You should not use double quotes inside your replacement.
You can study about delimiters from here : **https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/209681-slash-delimiter.html.**